# Why UIButton frame is reset by setTitle: forState: method

Tags: ios, objective-c

The problem is the following:

In a certain moment, the button's position is changed. Following this, the button's title must be changed too.

The position is changed by an animation (UIView animation block), and when the title is set, the frame is back to original values (before the animation).

So... How can I fix that? And why that happens?

UPDATE with code

```
CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;
buttonFrame.origin = CGPointMake(16, 80);
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
    [self.button setFrame:buttonFrame];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self.button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // can be here...
}];
```

Doesn't matter where I put setTitle:ForState: method, the frame back to the original values.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to receive any help without showing your code.

Comment: Code or didn't happened

Comment: Updated with code. Thanks.

Comment: Where you are setting title ? Show that code too

Comment: @TheTiger You understand what I mean with that.

Comment: What you're seeing is the consequence of setting a frame when using auto layout. The frame will set properly, but as soon as some other event (like changing the button's title) causes the system to re-layout its views, the frame will go back to the one determined by the constraints. You need to do it like I said in my answer.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. Same problem here.
But it only happens in simulator 5-5s(8.1)
not in 7.1.
Any luck finding a solution ?
I my case, autoLayout is on but i didn't set any custom constraints.

Answer (score 5):

Try disabling Autolayout on your UIViewController. For me, sometimes Autolayout causes some pesky layout behavior. Especially when I'm using animation.

**EDIT**

This worked for me if Autolayout is ON:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
     self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200,-200);
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.button setTitle:@"YourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}];
```

Comment: I use Auto Layout for other UI elements, which are related. It's not an option disable it.

Comment: Did you try using a transform like @Cyrille suggested? That may play nicely with Autolayout.

Answer (score 5):

When you use auto layout you should not set any frames. Instead, if you want to change the button's position, you should make IBOutlets to constraints in IB and modify their constants. For instance, if your button has a constraint to the top and left side of the screen (I'll call them leftCon and topCon), you could do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
    self.leftCon.constant = 16;
    self.topCon.constant = 80;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: The problem is that I change position of other elements. And [self.view layoutIfNeeded] reset all frames, and all UI elements go back to original state. Got worse...

Comment: @RodrigoSalles -- You shouldn't do that if you're using auto layout. Either turn that off, or do all frame changes by changing constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `transform` instead of changing the frame :

`button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100,-100);`

Comment: @RodrigoSalles - I'm getting the same unwanted behavior you are when trying to animate the frame with Autolayout ON. However when I instead use a transform inside the animation block, with Autolayout still on, it works correctly.

Comment: A transform does not change the frame, it is applied after doing the layout. It is not affected by autolayout or autosizing, that's why it works. @RodrigoSalles, you have to have an error elsewhere.