# Perform a Segue after animation but animated items get back to their previous position

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have this problem, i have set in the `Storyboard` 2 `UIButton` and after touching one of them they must move, so i implemented this using animation, and works fine. But after the completion of the animation i'm performing a modal segue, the problem is that while modal segue is starting, raising the new `UIView` from the bottom, the 2 `UIButton` return to their previous place, where i set them in the `Storyboard`, and it's orribile to see. How could i solve this? 
Here's the code i'm using

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *maleBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *femaleBtn;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_maleBtn addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(chooseGender:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_femaleBtn addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(chooseGender:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (IBAction)chooseGender:(id)sender
{
    CGRect maleFrame;
    CGRect femaleFrame;

    if (sender == _maleBtn) {
        maleFrame = self.maleBtn.frame;
        maleFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2) - 15;

        femaleFrame = self.femaleBtn.frame;
        femaleFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    }
    else {
        maleFrame = self.maleBtn.frame;
        maleFrame.origin.x = -self.view.bounds.size.height;

        femaleFrame = self.femaleBtn.frame;
        femaleFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2) - 15;

    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _maleBtn.frame = maleFrame;
                         _femaleBtn.frame = femaleFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if(sender == _maleBtn)
                             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMale" sender:self];
                         else
                             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toFemale" sender:self];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Do you have something in your viewWillAppear? And have you tried using CGRectMake for positioning?

Comment: No this is all my .m have nothing else, just i set the button in those positions in the storyboard

Comment: Just to try it out in your completion put this in: _maleBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20); Before the segue. Perform the segue and and dismiss and see if the button has changed back to original position. Or if it has resized and moved.

Comment: Still getting back to original position!

Comment: Then I suspect it is a similar problem to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634244/why-is-animated-uibuttons-position-reset-when-clicked?rq=1

Comment: Probably you should call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method asynchronously using GCD, i.e. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueId sender:self]; })`

Comment: @LeelooLevin yes that post is similar to mine, the new scene cancel all the previous animation and reset the View, in this way everything go back to their default positions, but i didn't understand how could this be solved

Answer (score 0):

At the top you make a bool or add a property in your .h if you like. But I would just use a local variable for this.

```
BOOL didAnimate;
```

In viewDidLoad you set it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set the bool value here to no;
    didAnimate = NO;

    [_maleBtn addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(chooseGender:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_femaleBtn addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(chooseGender:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Use it here, and I also took the liberty to rewrite your code a bit.

```
- (IBAction)chooseGender:(id)sender
{
    CGRect maleFrame;
    CGRect femaleFrame;

    if (sender == _maleBtn) {
        maleFrame = self.maleBtn.frame;
        maleFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2) - 15;

        femaleFrame = self.femaleBtn.frame;
        femaleFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    }
    else {
        maleFrame = self.maleBtn.frame;
        maleFrame.origin.x = -self.view.bounds.size.height;

        femaleFrame = self.femaleBtn.frame;
        femaleFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width/2) - 15;

    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _maleBtn.frame = maleFrame;
                         _femaleBtn.frame = femaleFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     didAnimate = YES;
                     }];

     if(sender == _maleBtn && didAnimate){
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMale" sender:self];
     }
     else if((sender == _femaleBtn && didAnimate)){
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toFemale" sender:self];
     }
     else{
     NSLog(@"failure to transition");
     }
}
```

I have not tested this and there might be spelling errors and such. So copy/paste might not work.

Comment: It does not work simply because the if statement for segue is called `BEFORE` the completion handler, so the `didAnimate` is always false. I tried something similar and faced this problem that's in your code too. Putting it in the completion handler it's useless, so i couldn't come out with a solution.

Comment: Did you solve it? As I have thought up a solution to your problem.